# $2 \cos^{-1}x =\sin^{-1}(2x \sqrt {1-x^2})$ is valid for which values of $x $

Tags: trigonometry

> **Problem**: $2 \cos^{-1}x =\sin^{-1}(2x \sqrt {1-x^2})$ is valid for which values of $x $
>
> **Solution**:  $2 \cos^{-1}x =\sin^{-1}(2x \sqrt {1-x^2})$
>
> $2 \cos^{-1}x =2 \sin^{-1}x$
>
> $ \cos^{-1}x = \sin^{-1}x$

Am I doing right ?

Comment: @jibounet, but $\cos^{-1}(-1)=\pi$ and $\sin^{-1}0=0$

Comment: You're right, sorry !

Comment: @jibounet, could you please verify my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the principal value of $\arccos x$ lies in $\in[0,\pi]$

$\implies 2\arccos x$ will lie in $\in[0,2\pi]$

Again as the principal value of $\arcsin x$ $\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$

Observe  that the intersection of region is $[0,\frac\pi2]$

So, $\sin^{-1}(2x \sqrt {1-x^2})=2\arccos x$

if $0\le 2\arccos x\le \frac\pi2\iff 0\le \arccos x\le\frac\pi4\iff 1\ge x\ge\cos\frac\pi4=\frac1{\sqrt2} $

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear to me

Comment: @rst, my pleasure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, we are looking for the *solutions* to:

$$2\cos^{-1}(x)=\sin^{-1}\Big(2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}\Big)$$

This is the sort of problem where a graph can help you gain intuition with respect to the interval over which the equation is valid:

See, e.g., [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20cos%5E%28-1%29%20%28x%29%20=%20sin%5E%28-1%29%20%282x%20sqrt%20%281-x%5E2%29%29):

[image]

As you can see from the graphs of $\color{blue}{\bf 2\cos^{-1}(x)}\,$ and $\,\color{purple}{\bf \sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1 - x^2})}\,$ above, the two curves *coincide* on the interval $\left[\dfrac{\sqrt 2}2, 1\right]$.

You can confirm, algebraically, that the *solutions* to the given equation consists of those values of x at which the two graphs intersect, so that the interval over which *equality holds* is $$\dfrac {\sqrt 2}2 \leq x \leq 1.$$

Comment: Very nice illustration. I see that two curves coincide in that interval. +)

Comment: @amWhy: I think pictures are a huge help too! +1